# Firebase Analytics on iOS Share Extension

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-analytics

Can Firebase Analytics events be logged from iOS App Extension such as Share Extension? I've added analytics on the main app and they are working fine and can be viewed from debug view.

For share extension I have added new app on firebase with the different bundle id and configured and added events. However I cannot see any events being logged into firebase console. Is there anything special I have to do to enable support for events from extensions? For debugging I enabled the debug mode using

```swift
FirebaseConfiguration.shared.setLoggerLevel(_:)
```

After that I could see console messages that were saying events logged or so, but however none of the events are being sent to the console nor they are leaving the app (Checked through Charles Proxy App). Not sure what I've missed out on. Any help is appreciated.

I can post the code but not sure how helpful that would be as it's just calling below after the viewDidLoad is called on Extension.

```
FirebaseApp.Configure()
```

Then using

```swift
Analytics.logEvent("name", parameters: [:])
```

Xcode console output looks as follows with Logger Level set to `.debug`

```bash
[FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.9.4.0 started
[FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see website link removed)
[FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS023009] Debug logging enabled
[FirebaseInstallations][I-FIS002001] -[FIRInstallationsIDController installationWithValidAuthTokenForcingRefresh:0], appName: __FIRAPP_DEFAULT
[FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS002002] APMExperimentAlarm scheduled to fire in approx. (s): 2754.831679821014
[FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS800023] No pending snapshot to activate. SDK name: app_measurement
[FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS029014] Successfully parsed a configuration. Version: XXXX
[FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS023016] Analytics is ready to receive events
[FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS023087] User property set. Name, value: _sid, XXXXX
[FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS023051] Logging event: origin, name, params: auto, _s, { ... }
[FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS023072] Event logged. Event name, event params: _s, { ... }
[FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS012018] Saving bundle. size (bytes): 639
[FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS023116] Bundle added to the upload queue. BundleID, timestamp (ms): 14, 1661233218364
[FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS023103] Event is under real-time event count daily limit. Marking the event as real-time. Event name, parameters: _s, { ... }
[FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS900000] Uploading data. Host: https://app-measurement.com/a
[FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS901006] Received SSL challenge for host. Host: https://app-measurement.com/a
[FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS023044] Successful upload. Got network response. Code, size: 204, 0
...
```

Answer (score 4):

*Firebaser here.*

Currently, Firebase Analytics does not support iOS extensions. There's already an internal request for this for our engineers to support this feature in the future. I've filed this case as another vote in favor of its implementation. However, I can't provide any details or timelines on when this might be addressed. For now, I suggest keeping an eye out for updates on our official blog and [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/releases) for any updates.

Comment: Thank you. Hopefully Firebase Analytics will support extension soon.

Comment: I'm using Google Analytics Measurement Protocol(GA4) but its not showing in dashboard as well.

Its working for newly created app but not working in my other app. How is that possible ? Do you have any idea about that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can send events from the app extension using Google Analytics Measurement Protocol (GA4).

See [Send Measurement Protocol events to Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/sending-events?client_type=firebase). You will just need to implement it by yourself, but we are using it on watchOS production app and it works just fine.