Send analytics in Swift when remote push notification appears?
I have a notification extension which allows to customize notification content. When remote notification comes it is passed through this extension to customize a notification appearance.
Is it possible to send analytics when notification appears on the screen? Found no information about it.
Is it possible to connect analytics to this extension? And does Apple pass such apps into App Store?

I think it is not possible. See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/74801216/1332734
